# Translate file paths in quickfix list

Tags: microsoft-windows, quickfix, makeprg, errorformat, filenames

I'm using msys + vim + ninja + MSVC on windows.

When building, the quickfix list has errors that use the windows path, ie
c:\work\folder\file.cpp

Vim handles it ok-ish, it can open the files, but ideally it should translate those into msys style paths, ie
/c/work/folder/file.cpp

and better yet, I'm in the C:\work folder,
so it should become a relative path, ie folder/file.cpp

The messages are coming back from Ninja, which is using MSVC's cl.exe to build.

Comment: Do you run Vim from the msys command prompt? Have you check the the output of the ninja command? I suspect this is more a ninja problem than a Vim problem.

Comment: I do run vim from msys, it is the msys vim.
And, yes the output of Ninja does have the Windows C:\ paths.
My goal is to see if vim can auto-translate these windows-style paths to unix - perhaps with a plugin or script.

Answer (score 1):

If vim is able to resolve your paths correctly and the issue is simply the visual component in the quickfix list, then you can customize its output with `quickfixtextfunc` (:h qftf) as follows (untested since I don't have a machine running Windows):

```
set qftf=QuickFixTextFunc
function QuickFixTextFunc(info) abort
 if a:info.quickfix
     let qfl = getqflist(#{id: a:info.id, items: 0}).items
 else
     let qfl = getloclist(a:info.winid, #{id: a:info.id, items: 0}).items
 endif
 let l = []
 for idx in range(a:info.start_idx - 1, a:info.end_idx - 1)
     let e = qfl[idx]
     let fname = bufname(e.bufnr)->fnamemodify(':p')
     let fname = 'c:' .. substitute(fname, '/', '\', 'g')
     let path = split(fname, ':')
     let letter = path[0]
     let fname = letter .. substitute(join(path[1:], ''), '\', '/', 'g')
     let lnum = e.lnum
     let col = e.col
     let type = e.type
     call add(l, fname .. '|' .. lnum..' '.. col .. '|' .. e.text)
 endfor
 return l
endfunction
```

The quickfix entries should looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In BuildToolsWrapper I have a [hook for translating cygwin pathnames into gvim(-win32) pathnames](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/project/compiler/BTW/cygwin.vim).

The approach I've taken consists in piping `make`/`ninja`... output into another program that'll do the translation. It's done directly in the `&makeprg` option.

It could be done in pure vimscript as well. For instance, I have a filter that changes filenames after the compilation (event triggered on `QuickFixCmdPost`) where i do some dark magic in order to update the buffers registered in the quickfix list: https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/project/compiler/BTW/substitute_filenames.vim

I think this approach/workaround is convoluted and best avoided, and we should prefer filtering error messages (and thus changing filenames) directly in the `&makeprg`.

Comment: When I started reading the question I was sure Luc would have an answer :)

Comment: Very neat, and looks like it could work, but didn't quite work for me.
I've opened a draft PR on your github, at least it now loads in my env (msys),
so I guess now it is a problem with the pattern matcher.  I'm not familiar enough with Perl to fix myself...
Oh and I use "ninja -C build-folder" and not make.  I added a Makefile that calls ninja for now.
I wonder if we can fix it up so it works?

Comment: I'm currently trying to fix the CMake compilation chain which is a mess. I may have troubles to provide you with a solution as I don't use msys. I'll see this weekend whether I could provide you with a solution. If you have perl, this should be doable.